# Text is deforming my div

Tags: html, css

The text is deforming my box.

here is what I have:

```
<div class="BigOne" ></div>
<div class="leftOne" ></div>
 <div class="rightOne">This text is deforming the "leftOne"</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
  .leftOne    {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 3px dashed #444;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

  .rightOne    {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 3px dashed #444;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**How can I precent the text of right div for example, from deforming left div?**

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand. With `width: 100%;` the divs are the entire width of the window, one above the other. Please explain more, or maybe you forgot to include some pertinent other html.

Comment: nop, the div depends of the with of the "BigOne" and its diferent for each screen, in this case i cannot use in px because is diferent for eacch scrren resolution

Comment: Please explain in what way you define "deforming".

Comment: when I enter a text the in one of the divs the width of this div gets bigger so it dosent ocupate 50% but 70% for example, thanks for helping

Comment: I'm still confused. Your css specifies `width:100%` and according to the supplied html, .leftOne and .rightOne are NOT within any other object, so they take the entire screen width. Not 50% as in your comment.

Comment: Maybe you could fix up this to show the exact problem. https://jsfiddle.net/eefmb32z/2/

Comment: Ok im sorry my question was not clear take a look here you will understand https://jsfiddle.net/eefmb32z/3/

Comment: The table seemed to play hell with it, but how about this? https://jsfiddle.net/eefmb32z/4/

Comment: If you want to use a table, you need to apply the css to the table cells, not the divs within the cells.

Comment: Thats perfet thank you guys, thank you @LilDevil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand from your question and explanation, you want the width of `leftOne` and `rightOne` to always be the same size regardless of `BigOne`'s width. Then you'd want to change the width to `50%` instead of `100%` like so:

```
.leftOne, .rightOne {
    float: left;
    width: 50%; /* Change this to 50% instead of 100% */
    height: 100%;
    border: 3px dashed #444;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Take note that you can refactor the CSS because both classes have the same styling. If you want to apply different styling to each of them, you can separate them back.

I also noticed that you have set the height of both of them to `100%`. If you want them to maintain the same height, you need to specify the height of `BigOne` class. Eg:

```
.bigOne {
    width: 100%; /*or whatever width you want to set it to */ 
    height: 100px; /*or whatever height you want to set it to */ 
}
```

Another thing, you have an extra `</div>` on the first line. Remove it and your code should work.

```
<div class="bigOne">
    <div class="leftOne"></div>
    <div class="rightOne">This text is deforming the "leftOne"</div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps.